# server not running and built file not being watched with Gulp task and nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, nodemon

I am trying out `gulp` but I am having trouble getting my built backend to run and also enable watching on the file.

My code is based on this [tutorial](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-II) and this [code](https://github.com/jlongster/backend-with-webpack/blob/part2b/gulpfile.js#L55)

Here is my `gulpfile.js` the bottom of the code snippet is where gulp tasks are named:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var DeepMerge = require('deepmerge');
var nodemon = require('nodemon');


// for excluding the building of node_modules in the backend
var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules').filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
}).forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
});

// generic config
var defaultConfig = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        'react',
                        'es2015'
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

// if not production build
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    // defaultConfig.devtool = '#eval-source-map';
    defaultConfig.debug = true;
}

// build config using overrides
function buildConfig(config) {
    return DeepMerge(defaultConfig, config || {});
}


var backendConfig = buildConfig({
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "server/server.js"),
    // tells webpack not to touch any built-in modules
    target: "node",
    externals: nodeModules,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: 'index.js'    
    },
    pluguns: [

    ]
});

var host = "localhost";
var port = 3000;

var frontendConfig = buildConfig({
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "app/index.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/bundle"),
        filename: "main.js"
        // publicPath: 'http://' + host + ':' + port + 'pubic/bundle'
    },
    plugins: [

    ]
});

function onBuild(done) {
    return function(err, stats) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + err);
        } else {
            console.log(stats.toString());
        }
        if (done) {
            done(); 
        }
    }

}

// build frontend
gulp.task('build-frontend', function(done) {
    webpack(frontendConfig).run(onBuild(done));
});

// watch frontend
gulp.task('watch-frontend', function(done) {
    webpack(frontendConfig).watch(100, onBuild());
});

// build backend
gulp.task('build-backend', function(done) {
    webpack(backendConfig).run(onBuild(done));
});

// watch backend
gulp.task('watch-backend', function(done) {
    webpack(backendConfig).watch(100, function(err, stats) {
        onBuild()(err, stats);
        nodemon.restart();
    });
});


gulp.task('build', ['build-frontend', 'build-backend']);
gulp.task('watch', ['watch-frontend', 'watch-backend']);
gulp.task('run', ['watch-frontend', 'watch-backend'], function() {
    nodemon({
        execMap: {
            js: 'node'
        },
        verbose: true,
        watch: ['server'],
        script: 'build/index.js',
        ext: 'js json'
    }).on('restart', function(files) {
        console.log('Restarted due to: ', files);
    });
});
```

Project structure:

[image]

Currently, running `gulp run` hangs and this is my output:

```
$ gulp run
[09:58:17] Using gulpfile ~/Development/projects/slack/slack/gulpfile.js
[09:58:17] Starting 'watch-frontend'...
[09:58:17] Starting 'watch-backend'...
Hash: 381ef159ea681b942d5f
Version: webpack 1.12.14
Time: 5300ms
   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.js  2.25 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} index.js (main) 765 bytes [rendered]
    [0] ./server/server.js 723 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] external "hapi" 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable]
Hash: f7da7679b954a4fc9f6f
Version: webpack 1.12.14
Time: 6230ms
  Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  832 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} main.js (main) 787 kB [rendered]
    [0] ./app/index.js 273 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
  ...
  ...
  [211] ./~/react-router/lib/browserHistory.js 596 bytes {0} [built]
  [212] ./~/react-router/~/history/lib/createBrowserHistory.js 5.22 kB {0} [built]
  [213] ./~/react-router/lib/createRouterHistory.js 579 bytes {0} [built]
  [214] ./~/react-router/lib/hashHistory.js 581 bytes {0} [built]
  [215] ./~/react-dom/index.js 63 bytes {0} [built]
```

The code is being built property because I can manually run `index.js` after the build and everything is working as it is supposed to.

Comment: So you basically having problem with `gulp-watch` I guess..?

Comment: @MoidMohd yes that is correct! Might have to do with nodemon as well